# HTML table fixed, right is displaying on the left

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this CSS for my HTML Table:

```
.TicketProperties {
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
        position:fixed;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" class="TicketProperties">
```

i want the table to display to the right of the page and fixed when scrolling but it is displaying on the left.

check my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RJ86Q/

Comment: why do you need the float if its position fixed? just remove the float and display properties and add - right:0.. so it should be {width:30%;    right: 0;position:fixed;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/RJ86Q/5/)**

**CSS:**

```
.TicketProperties {
    width:30%;  
    position:fixed;  
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this ok [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ86Q/2/)

```
.TicketProperties {
width:30%;
float:right;
display:inline;
    right: 0;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set position to fixed you need to specify it exactly, to have the table displayed on the right, add `right:0;` 
http://jsfiddle.net/RJ86Q/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try This CSS

```
.TicketProperties {
width:30%;
float:right;
display:inline;
right:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give right:0px

```
    .TicketProperties {
width:30%;
float:right;
right:0px;
display:inline;
    position:fixed;
 }
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/RJ86Q/9/